# Class object calling a class object

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am working on a project where a classobject has to call an other class method.
However it seems that it is not working in my code. So my question is if it is
possible that a element created in a class can call an other method of the same class?
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class table():

    def create_root(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        return self.root

    def create_frame(self, master):

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        return self.frame

    def sidetable(self, master, lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            self.labelside = Label(master, text=lst[i])
            self.labelside.grid(row=i+1, column=0)

    def toptable(self, master, lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            self.labeltop = Label(master, text=lst[i])
            self.labeltop.grid(row=0, column=i+1)

    def create_button_col(self, master, x, y, posles):

        def whitegreen(button, posles):
            if button["bg"]=="white":
                button["bg"]="green"
                posles.append([lenght,hight])

            else:
                button.config(bg="white")
                for i in range(len(posles)):
                    if posles[i]==[lenght,hight]:
                        del posles[i]
                        break

        self.button = Button(master, bg="white")
        self.button.config(command=lambda: whitegreen(self.button, posles))
        self.button.grid(lenght, hight)

    def tableteach(self, master, lenght, hight, posles): # I guess the problem lies somwere here...
        butlst = list(range(hight*lenght))

        for i in range(lenght+1, 1, 1):
            for j in range(hight+1, 1, 1):
                self.butlst[i*lenght+j]=table()
                self.butlst[i*lenght+j].create_button_col(master, i, j, posles)

a = table()
root = a.create_root()
frame = a.create_frame(root)
frame2 = a.create_frame(root)

timelst = ["10:00", "12:00", "14:00", "16:00", "18:00"]
weekdays=["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"]

a.toptable(frame, weekdays)
a.sidetable(frame, timelst)
posles = []
a.tableteach(frame, len(weekdays), len(timelst), posles)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which line or method are you unsure of?

Comment: i marked it... the line that says def tableteach

Comment: But you haven't described the problem. What is wrong?

Comment: I want the object "self.butlst[i*lenght+j]" to call the method " def create_button_col" that is in the class "table", but somehow it does not work. Because there should pop up a table with buttons in it.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `tableteach` your code begins by creating a local variable `butlst` that refers to a list.

```
butlst = list(range(hight*lenght))
```

Then in your `for`-loop you refer to `self.butlst` and expect it to be a list.

```
self.butlst[i*lenght+j]=table()
```

But you haven't defined it. `butlst` is a variable that is local to your method. `self.butlst` should be an attribute of your `table` instance, but your code doesn't actually create it anywhere that I can see. `butlst` ≠ `self.butlst`.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot!
Just one more question... 
I understand how the "self." in a method works, but I don't know when it is advisable to use it. Take the example of butlst. The program still works without a "self." in front of my butlst. So when do I have to use it and when don't I ?

Comment: An attribute like `self.xxx` becomes a permanent part of the class instance, so it is available from other methods as `self.xxx` and from users of the instance as `myinstance.xxx`. A local variable in a method (like `butlst`) disappears as soon as the method exits.